# MySQL error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Whenever I try to create the tables running my page called 'createtables.php', it can't create the table 'Ausleihe'.

```
<?php
    include 'connect.php';
    $query = "CREATE TABLE Schueler(
        SchuelerVorname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        SchuelerName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        StrasseUndHausnummer VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        PLZ INT(5) NOT NULL,
        Ort VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        SchuelerNummer INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    )";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    if(!$result) die ("Fehler beim erstellen der Tabelle 'Schueler': " .mysqli_error($conn));

    $query1 = "CREATE TABLE Buch(
        AutorVorname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        AutorName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        BuchName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        ISBN VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
        BuchNummer INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
    )";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
    if(!$result) die ("Fehler beim erstellen der Tabelle 'Buch': " .mysqli_error($conn));

    $query2 = "CREATE TABLE Ausleihe(
        AusleihDatum DATE NOT NULL,
        AusleihNummer INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        BuchNummer INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        SchuelerNummer INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        FOREIGN KEY (BuchNummer) REFERENCES Buch(BuchNummer),
        FOREIGN KEY (SchuelerNummer) REFERENCES Schueler(SchuelerNummer)
    )";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
    if(!$result) die ("Fehler beim erstellen der Tabelle 'Ausleihe': " .mysqli_error($conn));
?>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is it because of the foreign keys?

And sorry that my code is partly German, shouldn't really matter though.

Comment: A FOREIGN KEY (BuchNummer) can (logically) not be auto incrementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says exactly what the problem is - you can't have more than one `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. You will have to remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT` attribute from one of your columns. Probably something like this:

```
$query2 = "CREATE TABLE Ausleihe(
        AusleihDatum DATE NOT NULL,
        AusleihNummer INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        BuchNummer INT(6) UNSIGNED,
        SchuelerNummer INT(6) UNSIGNED,
        FOREIGN KEY (BuchNummer) REFERENCES Buch(BuchNummer),
        FOREIGN KEY (SchuelerNummer) REFERENCES Schueler(SchuelerNummer)
        )";
```

Comment: oh wow! thanks :) now I'm feeling very stupid ;D I'm more or less new to coding and didn't quite get the error message.. sorry! But thanks for your fast help :)

Comment: No worries. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The auto incrementation should be done on your Buch and Schueler table. You should use the query from Matt Spinks answer.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the mysql error itself has the answer. 'Ausleihe' table have three auto incrementing columns which is causing the error. You have to remove AUTO_INCREMENT from 'BuchNummer' and 'SchuelerNummer' columns so only 'AusleihNummer' will be left with auto increment.